# Swift - MyClass is not identical to NSManagedObject

Tags: swift, generics, core-data, subclass, nsmanagedobject

Can someone explain to me why the following playground code gives me the error

> `EventEntity` is not identical to `NSManagedObject`

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class Table<T: NSManagedObject> {
    func toFetchedResultsController() -> FetchedResultsController<T> {
        return FetchedResultsController<T>()
    }
}

class EventEntity: NSManagedObject {

}

class FetchedResultsController<T: NSManagedObject> {

}

class Factory<T: NSManagedObject>: NSObject {
    var fetchedResultsController: FetchedResultsController<T>

    init(fetchedResultsController: FetchedResultsController<T>) {
        self.fetchedResultsController = fetchedResultsController
        super.init()
    }
}

class TableViewDataSource: NSObject {
    init(factory: Factory<NSManagedObject>) {
        super.init()
    }
}

var dataSource: TableViewDataSource

let fetchedResultsController = Table<EventEntity>().toFetchedResultsController()
let factory = Factory(fetchedResultsController: fetchedResultsController)

dataSource = TableViewDataSource(factory: factory)
```

I had a problem with an app I'm developing in Swift. I created this playground to reproduce the problem.

What is the reason for this error? `EventEntity` is actually a subclass of `NSManagedObject` and `T` is a generics that specifies a `NSManagedObject` class requirement.

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to boil your problem down to a small amount of code that reliably reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your `TableViewDataSource` initializer:

```
init(factory: Factory<NSManagedObject>) {
    super.init()
}
```

Here, you're specifying that the initializer wants a `Factory<NSManagedObject>`, and then later you pass it a `Factory<EventEntity>`. These types are not *identical*.

I think what you meant to do was to specify that `TableViewDataSource` also works with a generic type (so long as it's *some* `NSManagedObject`), like so:

```
class TableViewDataSource<T: NSManagedObject>: NSObject {
    init(factory: Factory<T>) {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Comment: For several reasons I would like my TableViewDataSource not to use generics. That's why I created the "Factory" class. It was meant as "in the middle" class. Isn't it possible?

Comment: You should *ideally* be able to pass a `Factory<EventEntity>` to a method requiring a `Factory<NSManagedObject>`, but you can't. (This restriction doesn't apply to native Swift types: you can pass an `Array<Cow>` to a function requiring an `Array<Animal>` with no problem.)

Comment: Thanks Aaron for your time!